# How can I return a value within a nested function?

Tags: javascript, function, return-value, nested-function

Is it possible to return a value from a nested function? This is what I got so far and it doesnt work. In my code I am trying to return `eventId` from within the `request.execute()` function. I dont know if I am going in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     function insertDate(dateFormat) {
        var eventId = "";
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {                 // load the calendar api (version 3)
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId':       'primary',  // calendar ID
                "sendNotifications": true,
                "resource":         dateFormat      // pass event details with api call
            });

            // handle the response from our api call
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                if(resp.status=='confirmed') {
                    eventId = resp.id
                    console.log("eventId in execute: " + eventId)
                    console.log("successfully inserted")
                    return eventId
                } else {
                    console.log("failed to insert")
                }
                console.log(resp);
                console.log("2: " + resp.id);
            });
            return eventId
        });
        console.log("eventId on return: " + eventId)
        return eventId
    }
```

I put the function `insertDate(dateFormat)` in a loop and im adding the `eventId` which im trying to get from the `request.execute()` function into my `eventIdArray` as follows

```
var eventIdArray = [];
eventIdArray[i] = insertDate(dateFormat);
console.log("eventIdArray: " + eventIdArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't return a value from an asynchronous function call.

You can return promises, and use `Promise.allSettled` to wait until they're all done:

```
function insertDate(dateFormat) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // load the calendar api (version 3)
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId':       'primary',  // calendar ID
                "sendNotifications": true,
                "resource":         dateFormat      // pass event details with api call
            });

            // handle the response from our api call
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                if(resp.status=='confirmed') {
                    console.log("eventId in execute: " + resp.id)
                    console.log("successfully inserted")
                    resolve(resp.id);
                } else {
                    reject("failed to insert");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

var dates = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3'];
var promises = [];

dates.forEach(function (date) {
    promises.push(insertDate(date);
});

Promise.allSettled(promises).then(function (results) {
    // 'results' is an array containing all the event IDs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the code in insertDate in promise and then resolve the eventId and then use async/await to fill the array. you need to do slight modification to your code

updated code of yours

```
function insertDate(dateFormat) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var eventId = "";
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {                 // load the calendar api (version 3)
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId': 'primary',  // calendar ID
                "sendNotifications": true,
                "resource": dateFormat      // pass event details with api call
            });

            // handle the response from our api call
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                if (resp.status == 'confirmed') {
                    eventId = resp.id
                    console.log("eventId in execute: " + eventId)
                    console.log("successfully inserted")
                    //  return eventId
                    resolve(eventId);
                } else {
                    console.log("failed to insert");
                    resolve(-1); // just for indication -1 means not confirmed      
                    //or reject(-1);
                }
                console.log(resp);
                console.log("2: " + resp.id);
            });
            // return eventId
        });
        console.log("eventId on return: " + eventId)
        
    });
}
```

then wrap the filling of the array in async/await,
note that
you have to put async in front of the function that this loop contains in. I used fillEventIdArray just as an example for showing how to put async and use await inside it as await can't be used if the function does not contain async keyword

```
async fillEventIdArray(dateFormat) {
    var eventIdArray = [];
    //your for loop here and below is the code inside the for loop 
        const eventId = await insertDate(dateFormat)
        eventIdArray.push(eventId);
        console.log("eventIdArray: " + eventIdArray[eventIdArray.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to put the async function inside my for loop. Right now I am trying to do that and I am getting a `Unresolved variable or type async ` and a `Unresolved function or method fillEventIdArray() ` error

Comment: @John, yes but you have to put async in front of the function that this loop contains in. I used fillEventIdArray just as an example for showing how to put async and use await inside it as await can't be used if the function does not contain async keyword